# Equal bins in DAX equivalent of NTILE function

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to imitate [NTILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function of SQL in DAX. For a given number of bins, I would like a measure which returns the bin number for any value in a column. The bins should contain more or less equal number of observations.

So the parameters are:

- number of bins
- test value
- table column

Here is something similar in Excel:

```
= MAX( ROUNDUP( PERCENTRANK($A$1:$A$8, A1) *4, 0),1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In DAX, you can use the [`PERCENTILE.INC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/percentile-inc-function-dax) as the base for such a calculation.

```
Bucket = 
VAR N = 4
VAR Percentiles =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATESERIES ( 1, N ),
        "Percentile", PERCENTILE.INC ( Table1[Col1], [Value] / N )
    )
RETURN
    MINX ( FILTER ( Percentiles, Table1[Col1] <= [Percentile] ), [Value] )
```

For your data, the `Percentiles` table variable looks like this:

```
Value   Percentile
1       24.8
2       66.5
3       81.8
4       85.0
```

Then for each row in your original table, you take the minimum value from the calculated table where that `Percentile` column is less than or equal to the original table column `Col1` in that row.

---

Note that the above is for a calculated column. For a measure, you'd need to specify an aggregation for `Table1[Col1]` in the last line (e.g. `MAX(Table1[Col1])`).

Comment: I hope you had to think about it for a moment, not that you just shook it out of your sleeve:-) Thanks.

Comment: The basic idea was clear immediately but it took a bit to nail down the details. ;)

Comment: It's good to mention that `Bucket` of your code is a calculated column, not a measure.

Comment: Why can't we use `VAR MyColumn = Table1[Col1]` in the beginning of the code and then reference it? The code throws an error in the line `PERCENTILE.INC ( MyColumn, [Value] / N )`. The error message: `The PERCENTILE.INC function only accepts column reference as an argument number 1`. The FILTER function does not have any problem with accepting MyColumn variable.

Comment: Unfortunately, many DAX functions require a pure column reference (rather than variable or expressions) for arguments. I haven't found a way around that yet.

Comment: Hi Alexis, I am struggling to modify your solution to calculate Bucket by category. Can you please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71048300/1903793

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin Maybe try replacing %tile() with CALCULATE ( %tile(), ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Category] ) )

Comment: It will not work because VAR Percentiles at its earliest stage needs to be calculated by category.

Comment: I was suggesting modifying the VAR Percentiles definition

Comment: In that case I could not wrap PERCENTILE.INC with CALCULATE because [Value] column becomes unrecognizable.

Comment: Please see my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/71048300/1903793 I was able to construct proper VAR Percentile table there but I am not able to pull appropriate value from it.