# DAX PERCENTILE.INC by category in calculated column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to calculate a quartile (ntile) by category using PERCENTILE.INC in a calculated column. My question is a variation to this question:
[Equal bins in DAX equivalent of NTILE function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59989628/1903793)

How to modify the accepted solution to the problem if we want to calculate the result by a category?

```
Bucket = 
VAR N = 4
VAR Percentiles =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATESERIES ( 1, N ),
        "Percentile", PERCENTILE.INC ( Table1[Col1], [Value] / N )
    )
RETURN
    MINX ( FILTER ( Percentiles, Table1[Col1] <= [Percentile] ), [Value] )
```

I tried this but the results are not desired values:

```
VAR N = 4
VAR Percentiles =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CROSSJOIN( VALUES( Tab[Category] ), GENERATESERIES( 1, N ) ),
        "Percentile",
            PERCENTILEX.INC(
                VAR Category = 'Tab'[Category] RETURN FILTER( Tab, 'Tab'[Category] = Category ),
                Tab[Quantity] * 1.0,
                [Value] / N
            )
    )
RETURN
    MINX(
        FILTER(
            Percentiles,
            Tab[Quantity] <= [Percentile]
                && 'Tab'[Category] = [Category]
        ),
        [Value]
    )
```

Edit.

Sample data:

```
Table = 
DATATABLE (
    "No", INTEGER,
    "Category", STRING,
    "Quantity", DOUBLE,
    {
        {  1 , "apple"  , 1 },
        {  2 , "apple"  , 5 },
        {  3 , "apple"  , 1 },
        {  4 , "apple"  , 4 },
        {  5 , "apple"  , 1 },
        {  6 , "apple"  , 2 },
        {  7 , "apple"  , 5 },
        {  8 , "apple"  , 4 },
        {  9 , "banana" , 9 },
        { 10 , "banana" , 7 },
        { 11 , "banana" , 6 },
        { 12 , "banana" , 4 },
        { 13 , "banana" , 5 },
        { 14 , "banana" , 7 },
        { 15 , "banana" , 8 },
        { 16 , "banana" , 9 }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I was suggesting in the comments from the prior thread.

```
Bucket =
VAR N = 4
VAR Percentiles =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATESERIES ( 1, N ),
        "Percentile",
            VAR K = [Value] / N
            RETURN
                CALCULATE (
                    PERCENTILE.INC ( Table1[Col1], K ),
                    ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Category] )
                )
    )
RETURN
    MINX ( FILTER ( Percentiles, Table1[Col1] <= [Percentile] ), [Value] )
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it produces desired results. Introducing VAR K was a neat trick because [Value] / N inside Percentile function returned an error: "Column 'Value' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression."

Comment: EARLIER might work too but variables are usually easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to put my solution to work:

```
Bucket by Category = 
VAR N = 4
VAR Percentiles =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CROSSJOIN(
            SELECTCOLUMNS( VALUES( 'Table'[Category] ), "TheCategory", 'Table'[Category] ), // Change column name to new name
            GENERATESERIES( 1, N )
        ),
        "Percentile",
            PERCENTILEX.INC(
                VAR Category = 'Table'[Category] RETURN FILTER( 'Table', 'Table'[Category] = Category ),
                'Table'[Quantity] * 1.0,
                [Value] / N
            )
    )
RETURN
    MINX(
        FILTER(
            Percentiles,
            'Table'[Quantity] <= [Percentile]
                && 'Table'[Category] = [TheCategory] // Here we can reference the new name
        ),
        [Value]
    )
```

It turned out that the only fix was to change the column name of Percentiles table [Category] to something else. So that when we reference the new name [TheCategory] it is clear that we reference Percentiles table and not 'Table'. This solution may not be optimized so I welcome any other solutions.